# Preserving function names when generating JavaScript from TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Currently, when you compile something like the following TypeScript program:

```
class Foo {
    Bar(): void {}
}
```

it generates the following JavaScript:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.Bar = function () { };
    return Foo;
}());
```

The `Bar` method is declared as an anonymous function. Is there any way to make TypeScript generate Bar as a named function? I'd prefer something like the following:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.Bar = function Bar() { };
    return Foo;
}());
```

This would make it possible to do proper inspection of method names at runtime.

### Update

After opening [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14054) on TypeScript's github repo, I got a response stating that:

> This is actually an ES6 spec compliance problem since ES6 class method names do get populated as expected.

The issue was added as a bug, so it appears the TypeScript team will be adding support for preserving function names.

Comment: In case you can't, take a look at reflect-metadata and the TS options around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind about the methods being assigned to the instance instead of the prototype then you can do this:

```
class Foo {
    Bar = function Bar(): void { }
}
```

Which will compiled to:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
        this.Bar = function Bar() { };
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work, as my code needs to work with arbitrary TypeScript programs, which I can't assume I can modify. Also, the methods needs to be assigned to the prototype.

Comment: You want to change the compiler behavior meaning that you compile this code. If you compile it, why can't you change it? 3rd party libs usually come compiled into js and may have definition files.

Comment: Sure, I can always transpile TypeScript into a new version of TypeScript that is compatible with what I want to do. (Although this answer doesn't even allow me to do what I want to do, since it's essentially creating a static method.) But that's a heavy lift that I'd rather avoid if there is an easier solution.  So the question is: is there an easier solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "transpile TypeScript into a new version of TypeScript", but I also don't understand your scenario or why you want to be able to do so. I don't think that it's possible without actually cloning the repo and changing the compiler, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The point of this question was to find out if there was already a way to do what I'm trying to do.  If there's not, I'll create an issue in the TypeScript github.